# Assigning Events using HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm learning JavaScript using EasyJavaScript app. I'm modifying presented examples in order to find out do i really understand them. At the moment I want to assign specific function to button without putting **onclick** within that button.

HTML:

```
<p>Test paragraph</p>
<button id="bg1">Button with function assigned</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function bgChange() {
    document.getElementById("bg1").onclick = changeBG;
}

function changeBG() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.body.style.color = "white";
}
```

Debugger shows nothing. Please explain me where i made mistake or whats wrong with my course of thinking.

Comment: Do you call `bgChange()`?

Comment: You tell us what you do *not* want ("without putting onclick") but what do you want instead ?

Comment: Simply to try out identical "strategy" presented in example. I figured out, the more ways of doing things im aware of, the better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to call the function `bgChange` on button click & execute `changeBG` by adding a pair of parenthesis `()` at the end

```js
function bgChange() {
  document.getElementById("bg1").onclick = changeBG();
}

function changeBG() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.body.style.color = "white";
}
```

```html
<p>Test paragraph</p>
<button id="bg1" onclick="bgChange()">Button with function assigned</button>
```

Comment: Your code works, however `changeBg()` gives `undefined`, then what's the purpose of this variable assignment `document.getElementById("bg1").onclick = changeBG();` ?

Comment: How can this be accepted answer if Krzysztof doesn't want `onclick` within `button`?

Comment: @MateuszDrost do you have a solution? Can you please show ?

Comment: @brk I don't need it to point out that this answer should not be accepted. You should show code without `onclick` within `button` or explain why it is impossible as Krzysztof asked in his question.

Comment: I was expecting a solution from you. I need to know how can you attach a event handler to a DOM element without onclick

Comment: I don't know how to do it. If you know this is impossible then you should in your answer explain why it is impossible instead of not really answering the Krzysztof's question. I encourage you to delete your answer.

Comment: SO is not only about saying impossible but also about suggestions and showing alternatives. This answer served the purpose of the question & he accepted it. I am not sure where is the fuss here & thanks for you suggestion but I am not deleting the answer. have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Defining functions won't run them. So you have to call them for them to do what you wanted. In your example you have to call `bgChange()` somewhere.

Can be done like this.

```js
function bgChange() {
    document.getElementById("bg1").onclick = changeBG;
}

function changeBG() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.body.style.color = "white";
}

bgChange();
```

```html
<p>Test paragraph</p>
<button id="bg1">Button with function assigned</button>
```

Consider defining functions are like adding your friend to your phonebook. If you need something from him, you first have to call him with parameters that he needs, then he will return you what you need.

Comment: Thank you. In example they didn't mentioned invoking it separately so i assumed it is unknow to me form of "onload" invoking.